# Why doesn't the function toggle work in this jsfiddle?

Tags: jquery, html

I am not very good in jQuery as you can see.

```
$(function(){
$('#change').click(function() {   
   $('#html').html("changed");
},
function() {
    $('#html').html("No change");
});
});
```

For testing purposes I tried making a fiddle with it, but i couldn't get it to work

Why changing just a simple html didn't work in this fiddle?

**Here is the fiddle-**
http://jsfiddle.net/kk7LZ/

Comment: click doesn't accept in/out(on/off) handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toggle()` has been removed from jquery version `1.9`

One solution is to use jQuery migrate plugin for detecting and restoring APIs or features that have been deprecated in jQuery and removed as of version 1.9.

Also you need to change `click` to `toggle`

```
$(function(){
    $('#change').toggle(function() {   
        $('#html').html("changed");
    },
    function() {
        $('#html').html("No change");
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kk7LZ/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event method has been remove from jquery 1.9

You can do

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Wbj2B/)</kbd>

```
var $html = $('#html');
$('#change').click(function () {
    $html.html(($html.html() == 'changed') ? 'no changed' : 'changed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are trying to do?

```
$('#change').click(function() {   
   $('#html').html("changed");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kk7LZ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`toggle` event method is removed in jquery 1.9, it no longer bind multiple click handler to an element, instead it toggle the visibility of the element: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

You can either use jquery 1.8 or implement `toggle` method yourself

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kk7LZ/4/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#change').click(function () {
        this.toggle = !this.toggle;
        $('#html').html(this.toggle ? "changed" : "No change!");
    });
});
```